# Why does my function not return the "errors" variable?

Tags: python

When I submit a form, the fields (year, name, email, color) are supposed to be validated and then the num_info, year_data, and num are sent.  If leave any fields blank, it is supposed to send back the error dictionary with all the invalid errors in it.  I keep getting "num_info referenced before assignment" as it seems to be trying to return the values on the last line, but that should  only happen if there are no errors and the dictionary is empty.

```
@app.route("/api/get-lucky-num", methods=["POST"])
def lucky_number():

    data = request.json

    errors = {}

    year = data['year']
    name = data['name']
    email = data['email']
    color = data['color']
    
    
    if year in range(1900, 2000) == False:
        year_err = {"year":"Year must be between 1900 and 2000"}
        errors['year_error'] = year_err


    if name == False:
       name_err = {"name": "You must have a valid name"}
       errors['name_error'] = name_err

    
    if email == False:
       email_err = {"email":"You must have a valid email"}
       errors['email_error'] = email_err

    
    colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "blue"]
    if color.lower() in colors == False:
        color_err = {"color":"Color must be red, green, orange, or blue."}
        errors['color_error'] = color_err

    
    if year in range(1900, 2000) == True and errors == False:
        info = all_data(year)
        num_info = info[0]
        year_info = info[1]
        num = info[2]

    
    if errors:
        return (jsonify(errors=errors), 201)
        
    else:
        return (jsonify(num_info=num_info, year_info=year_info, num=num), 201)
```

Comment: `{} != False` …

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
if year in range(1900, 2000) == True and errors == False:
    info = all_data(year)
    num_info = info[0]
    year_info = info[1]
    num = info[2]
```

Here, you want to execute the code inside the if statement if there are no errors, that's why you used the «errors == False» condition. BUT if you compare an empty dictionary to False, it will return False, because an empty dictionary is not equal to False.

So, you NEVER execute the code inside this if statement, because a dictionary is never False, even if it's empty, and the condition of the if will never be True. So, the variable num_info is never created.

What you want to do instead is:

```
if year in range(1900, 2000) == True and not errors:
    info = all_data(year)
    num_info = info[0]
    year_info = info[1]
    num = info[2]
```

If you print(not errors), when errors is an empty dict, it will print True. That's what you were trying to do. «errors == False» will never be True, even if it's an empty dict.

Comment: The issue ended up being setting my conditionals == to false, I used not instead for all of them and they worked.  Thanks for leading me to the right path.